# what is the meaning of the following lines of code exactly for knn algorithm

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, knn

I came across this code, but I don't know what the functionality of the following lines of code is:

```
negTrain = neg[:N]
posTrain = pos[:N] 
negTest = neg[N:]
posTest = pos[N:]
```

Could somebody guide me?

Comment: Do you **really, honestly** think that we will be able to guess what a random line of code with arbitrary variable names means, if you provide absolutely no context?

Comment: I can figure it out.  I'm writing a response :)

Comment: FWIW, given that it says KNN, it is a machine learning algorithm.  Also, the variable names of "train" and "test" give it away.  As such, it depends on who you ask, but I figured it out and my response is below.  As such, there is no need to be condescending.  You can obviously see that the OP is a new user.

Comment: It's not valid Python though, is it? If it's an argument to function call, then `keyword=1 or keyword=2` is not valid; if it is a statement then you can't assign to result of `x or y` in `foo=x or y=z`.

Comment: I think the `or` statements are outside of Python.  He wants to know what **either** of those statements mean.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any machine learning algorithm, you are trying to find **meaning** or **classification** of data.  How it starts is that you train your algorithm / machine first on **training** data.  Judging from these lines of code, you are using the KNN algorithm to do **logistic regression**.  This is a binary classification scheme where you are classifying something belonging to one class as **positive** and another class as **negative**.

One example would be a logistic regression machine learning algorithm where positive denotes you have a disease, while negative means you don't.  You take your training data and you decompose it into positive and negative examples.  You know which ones are positive and negative ahead of time.  You then train your learning algorithm so that you try and make the classification accuracy as high as possible.

Once you accomplish that, you have another set of data denoted as the **test** data, where there are positive and negative examples here too and you see whether or not this will do the same job in classification as your training data.  If your classification accuracy is worse, you'll need to go and revise your algorithm or parameters.  If it's better, then that's awesome.

Those four lines of code are basically saying the following.  For your positive and negative training samples, you take samples from 0 up to `N` - 1.  The test positive and negative samples are taken from `N` up to the end of the array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You take for training the first N positives and the first N negatives, this means position 0 to N-1.

You take for testing from position N until the end of the negatives and the positives.

Since this is KNN when you say train, that basically means that you will build a table with the training data and use the distance and the label of the training data to evaluate the testing data. There is really no training in KNN itself.